# How to join '\' and string to get unicode char

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a dictionary with chars from that range from Unicode, but unable to join '\' and 'u0061' for example

```
    for i in range(97, 123):
        dict[('\\u00' + (hex(i)[2:]))] = ''


    
'\u00' + '61' #does not work because after '\u' required 4 symbols
r'\u00' + '61' #returns '\\u0061' instead of 'a'
'\\u0061'[1:]  # slices both "\\"
```

Comment: So you want to add '\' to 'u0061'? But you want it to make it into a Unicode character?

Comment: for general purpose, use the built-in `chr` function. in your case, use `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: When I run the for loop it shows error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the corresponding character from an int, use the built-in `chr` function:

```py
>>> chr(101)
'e'
>>> chr(0x1F600)
''
```

However you seem to want to iterate over all lowercase letters. The constant `ascii_lowercase` from the `string` module is better suited for this purpose.

```
import string

dct = {} # don't use 'dict' as a variable name, it shadows the dict constructor

for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
  dct[c] = ''
```